# how to track the social media icons using DTM (Dynamic tag manager)

Tags: adobe-analytics

I have the below code in my web site.

I want to track each anchor tag using DTM. I know how to track single element. Since here we have a bunch of different elements, can anyone help how to track them using DTM? I don't want to create separate rule for each element. In a single rule how can we track these elements.

Comment: Add that code in your question!

Comment: I was not able to add the code in the question. So added it in comment section.

Comment: I was able to edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of what you can do.

For **Element Tag or Selector** put "`a.at-share-btn`" (no quotes). This will target all the relevant links first. We can look for this too in the next step, but "pre-qualifying" it with this will improve performance so that the rule is not evaluated against every single `a` click.

Then, under **Rule Conditions**, add a **Criteria** of type **Data > Custom**.

In the **Custom** box, add the following:

```
var shareType = this.getAttribute('class').match(/\bat-svc-([a-z_-]+)/i);
if (shareType&&shareType[1]) {
  _satellite.setVar('shareType',shareType[1]);
  return true;
}
return false;
```

This code looks for the class (e.g. "at-svc-facebook") and puts the last part of it (e.g. "facebook") into a data element named `shareType`.

Then, you can reference it using `%shareType%` in any of the DTM fields. **Note:** because this data element is made on-the-fly, it will not show up in the auto-complete when you type it out in a field.

Alternatively, in custom code boxes (e.g. if you are needing to reference it in a javascript/3rd party tag box), you can use `_satellite.getVar('shareType')`

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me try this n will come back to you if i see any issue.